# Looping a code through different and specific worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I am fairly new to VBA and I am trying to get better. I have a workbook that I am trying to loop a code through. but only on specific worksheets - not the whole book. Basically, I wrote a code that will reformat a pivot table as a table, and format the headers etc. This works perfectly in one sheet. But I have 10 more sheets this needs to be done with - for my colleagues (who is not excel wizards, it would be better if this could be done with the touch of a button - so to say).

I have googled for hours and tried many different stuff, sometimes I don't get an error but the code isn't applied to the other worksheets when running as macro.

(B11 is a static starting point for all sheets)

This is the code:

```
     Sub Ultimo_Pivot_Table()

'Start Loop? 
        
        'Select and copy pivot
            Columns("B:O").Select
            Selection.Copy
            Columns("P:P").Select
        'Paste pivot in new area
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme, Operation:=xlNone _
                , SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                :=False, Transpose:=False
        'Delete old pivot
            Columns("B:O").Select
            Range("O1").Activate
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
        'Select & Format as table
        With Range("B11")
            .Parent.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range(.End(xlDown), .End(xlToRight)), , xlYes).Name = "Table1"
        End With
        'Format Headlines
        With Range("B11")
            Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
        End With
            With Selection
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                .Orientation = 0
                .AddIndent = False
                .IndentLevel = 0
                .ShrinkToFit = False
                .ReadingOrder = xlContext
                .MergeCells = False
            End With
            With Selection
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
                .Orientation = 0
                .AddIndent = False
                .IndentLevel = 0
                .ShrinkToFit = False
                .ReadingOrder = xlContext
                .MergeCells = False
            End With
            With Selection.Font
                .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
                .TintAndShade = -0.499984740745262
            End With
            Range("B2").Select
            With Selection
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
                .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
                .WrapText = False
                .Orientation = 0
                .AddIndent = False
                .IndentLevel = 0
                .ShrinkToFit = False
                .ReadingOrder = xlContext
                .MergeCells = False
            End With
'End Loop? 

        End Sub
```

I have tried so many different things so this is the raw code without any attempts at looping. Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: How do you want to identify if a sheet needs to be processed or not? By name? By checking if it contains a Pivot table?

Comment: Show us what you’ve tried to change the other worksheets.  You don’t have any of that code here.

Comment: Also, the usual warnings about using .Select’s and relying on Active* objects in loops.  They are undesirable for many reasons and could easily be what’s causing you problems (though we can’t know because we haven’t seen what you’ve tried yet).

Answer (score 1):

Untested but you should get the idea:

```vb
Sub Tester()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    'loop over the sheets in the workbook containing this code
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        'call the sub and pass the sheet if there's a pivottable
        If ws.PivotTables.Count = 1 Then Ultimo_Pivot_Table ws
    Next ws

End Sub

Sub Ultimo_Pivot_Table(ws As Worksheet)

    Dim lo As ListObject
        
    ws.Columns("B:O").Copy
    With ws.Range("P1")
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    End With
    ws.Columns("B:O").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    
    Set lo = ws.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, ws.Range("B11").CurrentRegion, , xlYes)
    lo.Name = "Table1"
    
    With lo.HeaderRowRange
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .Font.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
        .Font.TintAndShade = -0.499984740745262
    End With
    
    With ws.Range("B2")
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .WrapText = False
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is an example of how to loop through worksheets. You can call your macro in each iteration:

```
Sub example()

    Dim i, n
    n = Worksheets.Count
    For i = 1 To n
        Worksheets(i).Activate
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

Comment: ... only that the code shouldn't use `Activate` or rely on the active sheet.

Comment: Being as new as I am - how would it look in my example? where would i place my own code?